# How to make Google Analytics send requests only from the main page of the site

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, google-analytics, google-analytics-4, universal-analytics

Me need send traffic only from one page of the site.
I'm using React v17 and React Router v5.

I used Universal Analytics, but it no longer supports it, and Google Analytics 4 sends traffic to all pages.
I tried react-ga4 and react-gtm-hook but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the current pathname(for example in `history.listen`) and only send a "pageview" event when the user is on the necessary page.

```
  if (window.location.pathname === '/') { // instead of '/' use necessary pathname
    GoogleAnalytics.send('pageview');
  }
```

or call `GoogleAnalytics.send('pageview');` once in `useEffect` in your page component

```
const HomePage = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    GoogleAnalytics.send('pageview');
  }, []);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that's not it. 
Universal Analytics sends data from all pages, but I need only the chosen ones.
I didn't find such settings